# i need to use variable in instead of direct date in shell script awk

Tags: shell, date, logging, awk

i need to use variable in instead of direct date.

```
cat file | awk -F, '{ if ($1>"2012-08-20 11:30" && $1<"2012-08-22 16:00") print }'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Then why don't you use a [variable](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html)?

Comment: i tried to use i got errors. i don't know how to use that.

Comment: What is in `file`? What is the expected output? What variable? What is in variable?

Comment: i am getting date from command line arguments and use that arguments as input for this command.

Comment: ex:
    cat file | awk -F, '{ if ($1>"$date1" && $1<"$date2") print }'

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown code, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.(In lack of samples I haven't tested it)

```
awk -v date1="2012-08-20 11:30" -v date2="2012-08-22 16:00" -F, '($1>date1 && $1<date2)'  Input_file
```

In case your variables are coming from shell to `awk` then following could help you on same, you could change date subtraction order as per your need too:

```
date1="2012-08-20 11:30"
date2="2012-08-22 16:00"
awk -v date_1="$date1" -v date_2="$date2" -F, '($1>date_1 && $1<date_2)'  Input_file
```